# Google Actions User Session Expire Timing

Tags: actions-on-google

How do we know user session got expired in Google Assistant Actions, will I get any requests from Google Assistant Actions stating this session's id got expired?

How do I come to know once the session got expired in Google Assistant Actions?

Answer (score 0):

You won't get any notice that a session has expired, but you could probably tell as the session will last as long as the conversation itself. You can also [add a boolean field in session storage](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/storage-session) to know if a session exists already.